# Support of Bohr-Jessen random variable at 1

Tags: probability-theory, analytic-number-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I am reading the book by E. Kowalski on Probabilistic Number Theory. Link to the book: [https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/probabilistic-number-theory.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Ekowalski/probabilistic-number-theory.pdf)

I am stuck on Exercise $3.2.4$. It seems that it should follow "elementarily" from Theorem $3.2.3$, but I can't think of any approaches that use the Theorem directly. Any hints and references are welcome. I am learning the basics of Probability theory on the go, so it would be helpful if you state the deep results from Probability theory used in the solution (if any).

[image]

Here $Z_D$ is the random Euler product defined by $Z_D(s) = \prod_p \left(1-X_p p^{-s}\right)^{-1}$, with $(X_p)_p$ being a sequence of independent random variables indexed by the primes,
which are identically distributed, with distribution uniform on the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1\subset\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

Comment: It would be much easier for others to answer this question if the question statement and relevant theorem were given here, instead of asking others to download and read the book.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thanks for the suggestion. I have added an image with the relevant statements.